# based on varied set of dates, predict a date r

Tags: r, compare, match, prediction

I have two datasets, the first dataset(DF1) is a treatment group, has ID, var1,  var2, result four variables.
ID and result are same for a person. 
but var1 and var2 are changing. Please notice each person has different row number. like ID1 has 3 rows, ID2 has only 2.

```
ID     var1              var2            result
 1      30                2013-11-23      2014-06-26
 1      30                2013-12-23      2014-06-26
 1      30                2014-1-23       2014-06-26
 2      60                2013-10-06      2014-05-10
 2      30                2014-01-6       2014-05-10
```

The second dataset (DF2)has same variable as ID, var1, var2. But it doesn't has result.

```
ID     var1              var2           
 a      30                2013-10-23      
 a      30                2013-11-23      
 a      30                2014-12-23       
 b      60                2013-10-06      
 b      30                2014-01-06       
 b      30                2014-02-03
```

My question is, what kind of method can I use to give each person in DF2 a result based on var1, var2 comparing to DF1? I think it may impossible for person in DF1 has totally same var 1 and var 2 as DF2..

Thank you so much for any help in advance!

Comment: your question is not entirely clear. can you give an example of your expected result? Also, take a look at `?merge`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match `var1` and `var2` in `DF1` and `DF2` and then assign a `result` to DF2 based on where there is a match? If so, this will work:

```
DF2$result <- NA
DF2[which((DF2$var1 %in% DF1$var1) & (DF2$var2 %in% DF1$var2)),'result'] <- DF1[which((DF1$var1 %in% DF2$var1) & (DF1$var2 %in% DF2$var2)),'result']
```

You will need to make sure `var1`, `var2` and `result` are not `factor` variables, otherwise this might give erroneous results. If you need them to be `factor`, first convert them to `numeric` or `character` and then back to `factor` after running the above script.